# devexpress GridLookUpEdit into RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit, or GridLookUpEdit into column cell

Tags: devexpress

I know I can set

`//RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit riglue
eePozycje.gvView.Columns[KolNazwa].ColumnEdit = riglue;`

but all I have is GridLookUpEdit.
How can I set GridLookUpEdit into column cel, or transform GridLookUpEdit  into RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit ?

//DONE
I found it in GridLookUpEdit.Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemGridLookUpEdittopic)

> The RepositoryItemLookUpEdit class contains settings specific to the
>   GridLookUpEdit control. You can access these settings via the editor's
>   GridLookUpEdit.Properties object. See the GridLookUpEdit topic for
>   details on the control.
>
> You need to create repository items as standalone objects only to
>   specify inplace editors for container controls (such as the XtraGrid,
>   XtraTreeList, etc)

I think you that [How to Assign Editors for In-Place Editing](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3085). Now If you want to set editors in particular cell then you have to handle the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic.aspx). The event occurs dynamically for each visible cell and allows you to supply an editor to individual cells, based on the position of the cell (its column and row).

**Refer this -** [Assigning Editors to Individual Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747)

example:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Column.FieldName == "FieldName") return;
   GridView gv = sender as GridView;
   string fieldName = gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["FieldName"]).ToString();
   switch (fieldName) {
      case "Population":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemSpinEdit1;
         break;
      case "Country":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
         break;
      case "Capital":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
         break;
   }           
}
```

Hope this help.