# Devexpress RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit, display value in cell disappears on mouse hover, but appears again on click

Tags: c#, .net, grid, devexpress

I have grid where in one cell is RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit with datasource. When I choose item from RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit, then lost focus from the row (e.g. by click mouse on other row), and then hover mouse on changed row- the value in cell with RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit disappears and says "Value is empty". But when I click again on that row, value appears. Any idea how to stop that disappearing?

`GridLookUpEdit glue = new GridLookUpEdit();
glue.Properties.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.Standard;
MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper(glue.Properties, GetMaterialyDataView(), "Kod", "Kod");
elementsEditThings.gvView.Columns[ColName].ColumnEdit = glue.Properties;`

```
public MyGridLookupDataSourceHelper(RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit edit, ITypedList dataSource, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        this.edit = edit;

        edit.DataSource = dataSource;

        edit.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        edit.ValueMember = valueMember;
        edit.ProcessNewValue += edit_ProcessNewValue;
    }
```

//DONE I changed GridLookUpEdit to RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit and now it works.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemGridLookUpEdittopic)

> The RepositoryItemLookUpEdit class contains settings specific to the
> GridLookUpEdit control. You can access these settings via the editor's
> GridLookUpEdit.Properties object. See the GridLookUpEdit topic for
> details on the control.
>
> You need to create repository items as standalone objects only to
> specify inplace editors for container controls (such as the XtraGrid,
> XtraTreeList, etc)

[devexpress GridLookUpEdit into RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit, or GridLookUpEdit into column cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772512/devexpress-gridlookupedit-into-repositoryitemgridlookupedit-or-gridlookupedit-i/35774015#35774015)